# Adding Items to Combobox manually from aspx page ,along with items added from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, devexpress

I have a problem here
I have year drop down list in my page, for that i am binding items from code behind,The maximum year i am adding from code behind is 2027.

But one user came up ,who wants to select year 2040, I am wondering whether I can manually add year 2040 from aspx page, so that no need to deploy my code.

Please help on this.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good way but you can do this using javascript. below is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = "2040";
            x.add(option);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs code just to show that drop down is some element of dropdown filled in server side code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```